# tkinter Treeview widget inserting data

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

This is my sample code. I want the items typed in the entry to be inserted to the treeview when the enter button is pressed. Im new to python and tkinter and there is not much tuts about treeview.

```
class PurchaseEntry(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
       tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
       self.controller = controller
       PurchaseEntry.configure(self, bg='white')

       label = ttk.Label(self, text='Purchase Entry', font=LARGE_FONT2)
       label.grid(row=0, columnspan=3, sticky='w')

       purchase_entry = ttk.Label(self, text='Purchase Entry:')
       purchase_entry.grid(row=1, column=0)

       self.entry_val = tk.StringVar()
       self.entry_1 = ttk.Entry(self, width=100, textvariable=self.entry_val)
       self.entry_1.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
       self.entry_1.focus()

       self.entry_btn = ttk.Button(self,text='Enter', command=self.insert_value)
       self.entry_btn.grid(row=1, column=4, columnspan=2, sticky='w')

       self.chat1 = ttk.Treeview(self)

       chat1 = ttk.Treeview( self, height=28, columns=('dose', 'date   modified'), selectmode="extended")
       chat1.heading('#0', text='item', anchor=tk.CENTER)
       chat1.heading('#1', text='dose', anchor=tk.CENTER)
       chat1.heading('#2', text='date modified', anchor=tk.CENTER)
       chat1.column('#1', stretch=tk.YES, minwidth=50, width=100)
       chat1.column('#2', stretch=tk.YES, minwidth=50, width=120)
       chat1.column('#0', stretch=tk.YES, minwidth=50, width=400)
       chat1.grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=4, sticky='nsew')

    def insert_value(self):
       value = self.entry_val.get()
       # Inserts data written in the entry box to the treeview widget when Enter button is pressed.
       # Clears the Entry box, ready for another data entry.
       self.entry_1.delete(0, 'end')
       self.chat1.insert('WHAT SHOULD I GIVE AS AN ARGUMENT?')
```

What should I pass as an argument?
Or is treeview the right widget for this or can someone suggest a widget suitable for this issue? thanks

Comment: I just want to know how to insert an item in the treeview using the entry widget after pressing the button.I have other columns because later I will include the date when that particular item was added.

Comment: This opensource project may help you a lot: https://github.com/talcs/tals_python_task_diary

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You seem to be interested only in how to insert data the user types within `Tkinter.Entry()` widgets into `ttk.Treeview()` after a `Tkinter.Button()` click.

I designed a simple interface to show you how to resolve this. You can adapt my solution to your problem.

Here is how the application demo looks like:

[image: screenshot of demo application running]

So I set a counter `self.i` to name the items. But you can add a label and an entry for this purpose instead and you insert items names similarly to the the other `Tkinter.Entry()` entries.

The insertion method is this one:

```
def insert_data(self):
    """
    Insertion method.
    """
    self.treeview.insert('', 'end', text="Item_"+str(self.i),
                         values=(self.dose_entry.get() + " mg",
                                 self.modified_entry.get()))
    # Increment counter
    self.i = self.i + 1
```

May be the main trick here is to retrieve the data the user types using [`get()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry.html) method which thing is represented by `self.dose_entry.get()` and `self.dose_modified.get()` actions.

This is done, you need now to bind this method to the button to be pressed to trigger the insertion action using the [`command`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm) option:

```
self.submit_button = Tkinter.Button(self.parent, text="Insert",
                                    command=self.insert_data)
```

## Full program:

```
'''
Created on Mar 21, 2016

@author: Bill Begueradj
'''
try:
    import Tkinter
    import ttk
except ImportError:  # Python 3
    import tkinter as Tkinter
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class Begueradj(Tkinter.Frame):
    '''
    classdocs
    '''
    def __init__(self, parent):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent=parent
        self.initialize_user_interface()

    def initialize_user_interface(self):
        """Draw a user interface allowing the user to type
        items and insert them into the treeview
        """
        self.parent.title("Canvas Test")
        self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.parent.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.parent.config(background="lavender")

        # Define the different GUI widgets
        self.dose_label = Tkinter.Label(self.parent, text="Dose:")
        self.dose_entry = Tkinter.Entry(self.parent)
        self.dose_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=Tkinter.W)
        self.dose_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.modified_label = Tkinter.Label(self.parent,
                                            text="Date Modified:")
        self.modified_entry = Tkinter.Entry(self.parent)
        self.modified_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=Tkinter.W)
        self.modified_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.submit_button = Tkinter.Button(self.parent, text="Insert",
                                            command=self.insert_data)
        self.submit_button.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=Tkinter.W)
        self.exit_button = Tkinter.Button(self.parent, text="Exit",
                                          command=self.parent.quit)
        self.exit_button.grid(row=0, column=3)

        # Set the treeview
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.parent,
                                 columns=('Dose', 'Modification date'))
        self.tree.heading('#0', text='Item')
        self.tree.heading('#1', text='Dose')
        self.tree.heading('#2', text='Modification Date')
        self.tree.column('#1', stretch=Tkinter.YES)
        self.tree.column('#2', stretch=Tkinter.YES)
        self.tree.column('#0', stretch=Tkinter.YES)
        self.tree.grid(row=4, columnspan=4, sticky='nsew')
        self.treeview = self.tree
        # Initialize the counter
        self.i = 0

    def insert_data(self):
        """
        Insertion method.
        """
        self.treeview.insert('', 'end', text="Item_"+str(self.i),
                             values=(self.dose_entry.get() + " mg",
                                     self.modified_entry.get()))
        # Increment counter
        self.i = self.i + 1


def main():
    root=Tkinter.Tk()
    d=Begueradj(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

**Note:**

I coded this in Python 2.7, but it should work if you're using Python 3.x.

Comment: Thank you so much. Helped a lot.

Comment: You are welcome. If you do not understand something in my code, do not hesitate to ask me at any moment @marcoalexis

Comment: Thanks for the example.  For those trying this in Python 3, just change the two imports on top to be: <code> import tkinter as Tkinter ; import tkinter.ttk as ttk   All the other lines can then stay as-is

Comment: is it possible to add button dynamically in  treeview, like,         self.treeview.insert('', 'end', text="Item_"+str(self.i), values=(self.dose_entry.get()+" mg", Button(self.treeview,text="click")))