# tkinter - ttk treeview: see column text

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I'm building a table in Tkinter using ttk's Treeview widget. However, after I inserted the columns they display it without text.
Here is the code:

```
w=Tk()
f=Frame(w)
f.pack()
t=Treeview(f,columns=("Titolo","Data","Allegati?"))
t.pack(padx=10,pady=10)
t.insert("",1,text="Sample")
```

Here the result:

[image: Treeview Result Image]

How can I solve?

Thanks

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36120426/tkinter-treeview-widget-inserting-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the headers for each column. I don't know if you want to use the same column names for the header or not so that is going to be my example. You can change the text to whatever you want. To define the header you will need to use `heading()` like this:

```
t.heading("Titolo", text="Titolo")
t.heading("Data", text="Data")
t.heading("Allegati?", text="Allegati?")
```

With those changes your final code should look like this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *


w=Tk()

f = Frame(w)
f.pack()
t = Treeview(f, columns=("Titolo", "Data", "Allegati?"))

t.heading("Titolo", text="Titolo")
t.heading("Data", text="Data")
t.heading("Allegati?", text="Allegati?")

t.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
t.insert("", 1, text="Sample")

w.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks, if I want to add data into a column how can I do it?

Comment: @MaicolBatti probably using `insert()` here is the [doc page](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html) for a lot of the treeview methods you will need.

Comment: t.insert("", 1, text="Sample", values=(1,2))