# Formatting SELECT results for a tkinter Scrolledtext widget

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I am trying to display the results from an SQL query in a scrolled text widget from tkinter. I am able to do this, however I envisaged the output to be more clean to look at.

```
import mysql.connector
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import scrolledtext
root=tk.Tk()
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="Cranmore1",
    database="scoutsdatabase"
)
print(mydb)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

Quote=("")
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM events")
myresults = mycursor.fetchall()
Quote = myresults

EventText = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, height=10, width=50)
EventText.insert("end", Quote)
EventText.grid(row=1, column=1,columnspan=5)
```

Yields a result which looks like this:
[image: Result]

I envisage something more along the lines of:

[image: this]

Further, is it possible to display the column headings as well?

The table looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Consider to use a [tkinter-treeview-widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36120426/tkinter-treeview-widget-inserting-data) instead.

Comment: Yep! That is the best approach.