# Tkinter - Get Entry text on double click (for loop)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pymysql

I'm making a program which gets database records with the PyMySQL module and then I want to display those records in Tkinter Entries. I already have the code to do that, but I want to add a functionality.

I want to give the user the functionality to **doubleclick** on an Entry of a row and get all Entry text of that row and parse them into the textboxes I declared before the For loop (UserID, First_Name etc).
Say I have 5 Entries per row. If the user **doubleclicks** on (for example) Entry number 2 of Row 1, I want to get the text from all Entries in Row 1 and parse them into the textboxes respectively.

This is the code I currently have:

```
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Flexbase") #Give window a name
window.update_idletasks()
width = 640
height = 480
x = (window.winfo_screenwidth() // 2) - (width // 2)
y = (window.winfo_screenheight() // 2) - (height // 2)
window.geometry('+{}+{}'.format(x, y))

GetRows_StringVariable = "SELECT * FROM SEC_USER"
cursor.execute(GetRows_StringVariable)
results = cursor.fetchall()

RowCounter = 1
ColumnCounter = -1
ListCounter = 0
RowListCounter = 0

rows = []

id_list = []
firstname_list = []
surname_list = []
username_list = []
email_list = []
password_list = []

tk.Label(window, text="Testing").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
UserID_TextBox = tk.Entry(window, width=20, bg="white") #Create text box
UserID_TextBox.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W) #Give the text box a position in the window
FirstName_TextBox = tk.Entry(window, width=60, bg="white")
FirstName_TextBox.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
Surname_TextBox = tk.Entry(window, width=60, bg="white")
Surname_TextBox.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
Email_TextBox = tk.Entry(window, width=60, bg="white")
Email_TextBox.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
Username_TextBox = tk.Entry(window, width=20, bg="white")
Username_TextBox.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W)
Password_TextBox = tk.Entry(window, show="*", width=20, bg="white")
Password_TextBox.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=W)

notebook = ttk.Notebook(window)
notebook.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

page1 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
notebook.add(page1, text="Mass Editing Mode")
tk.Label(page1, text=SQL_ID, fg="black", font="Arial 8 bold").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
tk.Label(page1, text=SQL_FIRSTNAME, fg="black", font="Arial 8 bold").grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
tk.Label(page1, text=SQL_SURNAME, fg="black", font="Arial 8 bold").grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W)
tk.Label(page1, text=SQL_USERNAME, fg="black", font="Arial 8 bold").grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=W)
tk.Label(page1, text=SQL_EMAIL, fg="black", font="Arial 8 bold").grid(row=0, column=4, sticky=W)


for row in results: # Page 1 TAB
    ColumnCounter += 1
    id_list.append(row[SQL_ID])
    a = tk.Entry(page1, fg="black", font="Arial 8 bold")
    a.grid(row=RowCounter, column=ColumnCounter, sticky=W)
    a.insert(0, row[SQL_ID])
    ColumnCounter += 1
    firstname_list.append(row[SQL_FIRSTNAME])
    b = tk.Entry(page1, fg="black", font="Arial 8 bold")
    b.grid(row=RowCounter,column=ColumnCounter,sticky=W)
    b.insert(0, row[SQL_FIRSTNAME])
    ColumnCounter += 1
    surname_list.append(row[SQL_SURNAME])
    c = tk.Entry(page1, fg="black", font="Arial 8 bold")
    c.grid(row=RowCounter,column=ColumnCounter,sticky=W)
    c.insert(0, row[SQL_SURNAME])
    ColumnCounter += 1
    username_list.append(row[SQL_USERNAME])
    d = tk.Entry(page1, fg="black", font="Arial 8 bold")
    d.grid(row=RowCounter, column=ColumnCounter, sticky=W)
    d.insert(0, row[SQL_USERNAME])
    ColumnCounter += 1
    email_list.append(row[SQL_EMAIL])
    e = tk.Entry(page1, fg="black", font="Arial 8 bold")
    e.grid(row=RowCounter, column=ColumnCounter, sticky=W)
    e.insert(0, row[SQL_EMAIL])

    RowCounter += 1
    ColumnCounter = -1
    ListCounter += 1
    RowListCounter += 1
```

This code produces a window with 5 Entries per row.

Comment: I think you need to add enough code to your question so it's runnable. That way more folks will likely work on providing you an answer. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You want probably [treeview widget](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html), [Treeview widget inserting data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36131160/7414759)

Comment: @martineau Thank you. I edited my code and made it runnable.

Comment: It's unclear why you need to parse are row because evidently, you have already split it into separate values for the multiple entry widgets per row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Florian Weimer already explained, you need to define one or more callback functions and attach it/them to each `Entry`.

Beyond that, I think you could (and should) eliminate as much of the  redundant code you have, which will make it much smaller as well as easier to work on and enhance. In software development, this is called the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), for "don't repeat yourself", principle.

Since I don't have your database, I had to add this line:

```
db_keys = results[0].keys()  # Get list of keys from the first result.
```

to obtain a needed list of the keys in each record/row. You may already have such list in your database schema or wish to create it in a different manner.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.constants import *


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Flexbase") #Give window entry name
window.update_idletasks()
width = 640
height = 480
x = (window.winfo_screenwidth() // 2) - (width // 2)
y = (window.winfo_screenheight() // 2) - (height // 2)
window.geometry('+{}+{}'.format(x, y))

GetRows_StringVariable = "SELECT * FROM SEC_USER"
#cursor.execute(GetRows_StringVariable)
#results = cursor.fetchall()

db_keys = results[0].keys()  # Get list of keys from the first result.

tk.Label(window, text="Testing").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

# Create textbox Entry widgets.
textbox_ids = list(db_keys) + ['Password']
textbox_widths = 20, 60, 60, 60, 20, 20
textbox_shows  = '', '', '', '', '', '*'
textboxes = {}
for i, (id, width, show) in enumerate(zip(textbox_ids, textbox_widths, textbox_shows), 1):
    textboxes[id] = tk.Entry(window, width=width, show=show, bg="white")
    textboxes[id].grid(row=i, column=0, sticky=W)

# Double-click callback function for items in result rows.
def double_click_cb(ev, row):
    # Replace current values in textboxes with those from the selected row.
    for key, value in row.items():
        textboxes[key].delete(0, END)
        textboxes[key].insert(0, value)

notebook = ttk.Notebook(window)
notebook.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

page1 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
notebook.add(page1, text="Mass Editing Mode")
nb_font = "Arial 8 bold"

# Create header row.
for i, key in enumerate(db_keys):
    tk.Label(page1, text=key, fg="black", font=nb_font).grid(row=0, column=i, sticky=W)

# Display results.
id_list = []
RowCounter = 1
for row in results:
    for ColumnCounter, key in enumerate(db_keys):
        id_list.append(row[key])
        entry = tk.Entry(page1, fg="black", font=nb_font)
        entry.grid(row=RowCounter, column=ColumnCounter, sticky=W)
        entry.insert(0, row[key])
        entry.bind("<Double-Button>", lambda e, r=row: double_click_cb(e, r))
    RowCounter += 1

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this after creating the `tk.Entry` objects:

```
    for obj in (a, b, c, d):
        def double_click(ev, RowCounter=RowCounter):
            print("selected row:", RowCounter)
        obj.bind("<Double-Button>", double_click)
```

(`RowCounter=RowCounter` is needed to capture the current row value.)

With the row number, you should be able to get what you need from the `results` object.

Comment: Do I add this after the for loop, outside the end of it?

Comment: No, this has to be called for each row (so that all entry widgets are affected). You need to call `bind` before incrementing `RowCounter`, so that the row number value is correct.

Comment: And how can I parse the row data into the textboxes? (I edited my question).

Comment: The answer to that depends on the format of the text you are trying to parse.